# ddrescue used all space and now I cannot boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, hard-drive, disk-usage, ddrescue

Good day y'all,
I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I was using GNU ddrescue to copy what can be copied from a failed disk to a brand new disk. The failed disk was mounted on /dev/sdb and the backup disk on /dev/sdc/.
I used the following command:

```
sudo ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc mapfile
```

Then, I don't know what happened, but my my internal SSD, where I have a dualboot with Ubuntu and Windows, got completely full, and the Ubuntu partition won't boot up  (the Windows one is fine).
I tried booting in recovery mode, and deleted some files from my videos folder (with rm command), totaling to some 2 GiB removed, but even if the specs list 121 GiB used (and 123 GiB total), the space used is 100% and the free space available is 0 kB.

My questions are: how can I free space and successfully boot up? And why did the main SSD fill up when I was rescuing the failed drive onto another drive?

Thanks in advance.