# fdimage of 800 GB?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, disk-usage, data-corruption

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
Why do I have a file in /home/myname/ called fdimage that is 805,8 GB? My SSD is a 500 GB one, and the partition allocated on it is only 125 GB... Clearly something is corrupted. What is going on here? Can I get rid of it?

The output of this command, however, tells a different story. According to du, this fdimage file only has a size of around 54.34 GB... How can Ubuntu give two different sizes for the same file?

```
du -a | sort -n -r | head -n 20

85129301    .
54340504    ./fdimage
12699488    ./Desktop
```

Again, the command stat /home/myname/fdimage returns a different size (805800542208 bytes = 805,8 GB)
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, and I couldn't find much information to this ./fdimage file, but from what I've read, I understood that maybe it's a kind of backup that Ubuntu automatically makes. Can I turn this off? I have my own backups, and I don't want Ubuntu eating more that half of my disk space.

In [my last post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395640/ddrescue-used-all-space-and-now-i-cannot-boot) I explained that, while I was using GNU ddrescue, my main drive completely filled up. I had to enter Ubuntu rescue mode to manually delete some files to have access again to the system. Is this related to the fdimage being this big? I had a file called mapfile in /home/myname but it was 0 kB in size.
The drive on which I wanted to create a copy is still empty (0 bytes). Maybe I filled up my main drive instead of the external one with the blocks from the bad disk I was trying to rescue? Maybe I used the wrong ddrescue command?
I cant't wrap my head around this, given that I could not find any files related to ddimage (apart from the above-mentioned mapfile that was empty) on my SSD.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `fdimage` is likely [a sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), which would explain the wildly different file size. You can confirm this with the following command:

```
ls -lsh fdimage
```

This will show the *occupied* size in the first column. If the occupied size is smaller than the apparent size then the file is sparse.

The file may have been created if multiple `ddrescue` commands had been tried, as [the name appears in examples from the Gnu documentation](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/ddrescue.shtml). You can certainly delete the file so long as nothing is currently using it and you do not need any of the data contained within.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, as a matter of fact, I tried multiple ddrescue commands, because I had to interrupt the recovery process.
The command ls -lsh fdimage returns 52G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 751G feb 28 14:47 fdimage... So, I think that it is actually 52 GB.

Comment: @Aleph_0: It's using 52G of disk space; it's logical file length is 751G.  `cat fdimage` would produce a stream of bytes 751G long, including many all-zero regions which were seeked-over instead of written explicitly when the file was created.  Neither size is wrong, they just have different meanings.

Comment: Spares files are a somewhat difficult concept to gasp. Think of it as a compressed file (like ZIP files). The file being magically decompressed when read. The (uncompressed) contents are about 800G but on disk the (compressed) file takes only 50G.

Comment: @max it may be more accurate to think of this sparse file as "an 805-page book with words on just 52 of those pages". Sparseness and compression are quite different as a compressed file is expected to be complete otherwise it cannot reconstitute the words, whereas a sparse file is known to be incomplete so is read from and written to with this in mind 